# Find intersection vertices of two polygons

Tags: python, coordinates, intersection, shapely

I have defined two polygons and I can find whether they intersect or not. 
I need to find the intersection vertices if they intersect or not ?

How can I do that ?

```
p1 = Polygon([(0,0), (1,1), (1,0)])
p2 = Polygon([(0,1), (1,0), (1,1)])
print(p1.intersects(p2))
```

This gives whether the polygons intersect but how to find the intersection vertex. I tried the following but it gave an error:

```
print(p1.intersects(p2).coords)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'coords'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intersects()` method returns `True` or `False` (Boolean) in `shapely`. You have to use `intersection()` method.

```
p1 = Polygon([(0,0), (1,1), (1,0)])
p2 = Polygon([(0,1), (1,0), (1,1)])
print(p1.intersection(p2))

# OUTPUT
# POLYGON ((0.5 0.5, 1 1, 1 0, 0.5 0.5))
```